press the / key to isolate an object, my blueprint background images also disappear
I need a little help. When I press the / key to isolate an object, my blueprint background images also disappear. I want them to keep showing even after isolating an object to model it separately. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The function you mention is called the Local View (Manual).

Local view isolates the selected object(s) so that they are the only ones visible in the viewport.

All you have to do in order to keep your background images visible when toggling On local view is to select them alongside the object you want to isolate.

Thanks for the response, but it's not feasible to have to select the blueprints and the object all the time. However, if that's the only way, I'll have to keep doing it like that. It would be interesting if Blender had a checkbox to keep my background images active even when I isolate objects.

@PauloMateus No, not really. That's the whole point of isolating objects - to isolate them. Just like in audio editing software the "solo" button - to isolate that audio track. If you want others isolated as well, you have to select them as well. Of course you could do that by having them all in a collection where you can select them together more easily.
